# JAVA - JMenuItem text corner left and right

Tags: java, html, jmenuitem

How to `JMenuItem` text can cornered right and left.

so I try use `html` code but it's not working

```
JMenuItem menuNew = new JMenuItem("<html><div align=left>Open</div><div align=right>Ctrl+O</div></html>", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icon/icon1.png")))
```

this is what I want :

[image]

and this is what I got :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `Ctrl+O` is called an *accelerator* and you should not be trying to set it in the JMenuItem’s text.

Use [setAccelerator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html#setAccelerator-javax.swing.KeyStroke-) instead:

```
JMenuItem menuNew = new JMenuItem("Open\u2026", new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icon/icon1.png")));
menuNew.setMnemonic('O');
menuNew.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl O"));
```

You can also specify the accelerator as an explicitly created KeyStroke rather than a parsed one:

```
menuNew.setAccelerator(
    KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O,
                           InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK));
```